# Quarkus, Gradle, and External dependencies; Objects from external dependency not serializable only in native mode

Tags: java, dependencies, quarkus, quarkus-native

I have a quarkus app, https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/tree/main/software/open-qm-base-station that relies on a dependency I make and build locally (it is available in the local maven repo). I have taken the steps necessary to make this work with Quarkus (empty `beans.xml` file), and works fine when operating in regular jar mode.

However,  when I operate in Native mode, the code can't make heads or tails of the objects from the dependency, typically throwing fits when de/serialization happens:

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.ebp.openQuarterMaster.lib.core.rest.ErrorMessage and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)`

I have tests running that confirm this (and seen in practice); when running in dev/ jar mode everything is fine. Native is a no-go. Is there anything I am missing on how to bring in non-jandex dependencies? I have attempted jandex plugins before but never seen them actually function.

To be clear:

`./gradlew test` -> works fine

`./gradlew testNative` -> fails

If testing for yourself, you will need to publish the dependency locally before attempting the quarkus app using `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`: https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/tree/main/software/libs/open-qm-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus Native not includes external dependencies.
You needs to include by yourself

[Link to SoF response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311514/how-can-you-access-resources-in-transitive-jar-used-in-native-image)

Comment: This solution seems.... silly. Is thee a plan to provide an easier solution in the future?

Comment: You can builds the uber-jar with all dependencies.
Or if you use the Docker you can write Dockerfile in such a way that all your files and dependencies got into work dirrectory